# overlay will not open

Tags: javascript, html, css

My span will not open up my modal. It will only open and work if i use `display:none;` on my overlay in my CSS file. Which means that when I do this, my modal opens up before my home screen. I want to have `display:none` and so the index opens first and then use the span to open the modal. Been stuck for too long on this issue. Any ideas?

I've tried switching the `z-index` but to no avail.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "100%";
}


function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```html
<!--The Overlay-->

<div Id="nav" class="overlay">



  <!--Button to close the overlay navigation-->

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

  <!--overlay content-->

  <div class="overlay-content">

    <a href="#">HOME</a>
    <a href="#">BLOG</a>
    <a href="#">GALLERY</a>
    <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>

  </div>


</div>

<div class="slideshow">



  <div class="slideshowcontent">


    <span style="font-size:60px;cursor:pointer;color:white;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>


    <h1>TRY AGAIN.</h1>
    <h2>Slowly getting there.</h2>

  </div>


</div>
```

Was hoping for the modal to open but nothing happens.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where is your modal? The buttons do exactly what you have them set to do in JS (the `x` closes the menu and the hamburger icon opens it). Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok so i finally found the issue. my span would not open the overlay because the width was set too 100% in css  and not 0. so the span was working all along but i was unable to see it because of the width setting at 100%. although my brain is still trying to work out how this makes sense. it works now but im still confused.